# Consent form available false react-native-google-mobile-ads

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native, mobile

I am trying to show GDPR consent form to EEA users using react-native-google-mobile-ads.  I have followed their instructions however when I call

```js
const consentInfo = await AdsConsent.requestInfoUpdate({
  tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
  testDeviceIdentifiers: [getDeviceId()],
  debugGeography: AdsConsentDebugGeography.EEA,
});
```

It returns

```json
{"canRequestAds": true, "isConsentFormAvailable": false, "privacyOptionsRequirementStatus": "NOT_REQUIRED", "status": "NOT_REQUIRED"}
```

I have already setup the GDPR message in admob and it shows as 'message on'.  I am thinking it's because I am not getting the correct testDeviceIdentifier, but honestly I am not sure what I am missing.

the getDeviceId() call is using the package react-native-device-info as specified in the documentation in react-native-google-mobile-ads.

Much appreciated!